# Custom listView in Fragment. Layout not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I've a listView in Fragment and works ok. Now I'm trying do a custom listView but I get not found.
With simple_list_item_1 works ok, with list item not working.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView mListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        //mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, songs);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, songs);
        mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

}
```

**Error**

```
error: cannot find symbol
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, songs);
                                                                           ^
```

symbol:   variable list_item

Comment: post logcat error here

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, songs);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable list_item

Comment: I posted my answer

Comment: I get same error

Comment: Post your full java class and XML class

Answer (score 0):

> try this if there is no crash and your list view in not creating,

Override `onViewCreated()` and declare `listview` in it and use `view` instead of getActivity()
like this

```
ListView mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

and

```
 mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, songs);
```

Copy and paste code there

```
  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        //mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, songs);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, songs);
        mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ListView mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item , R.id.text2, songs);
    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
}
```